# Does GC.Collect() disposes Font (or any instances who has implemented IDisposable) object .net 4.0 C# memory leak

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I have a C# .net 4.0 user control which uses lots of fonts and graphics object. This control is opened and closed multiple times and it leak memory. I am calling GC.Collect in the Dispose of this control.
My Question is if System.Graphics object for e.g. Font, Brush are used without "Using" or without Disposing it explicitly, is GC.Collect() going to clear that objects tool.

```
   void AssignFont()
    {
        Font f = new Font("Arial Narrow", 8);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposed)
            return;

        if (disposing)
        {
            // Free any other managed objects here. 
            GC.Collect();
        }

        // Free any unmanaged objects here. 
        disposed = true;
    }
```

This is just a simple example, i know that we should be calling System.Graphics object with using statement. My question what if those are not called with using and then GC.Collect is called from the Dispose method.

is GC.Collect() going to dispose and free the resource used by Font object.

Comment: This is somewhat a moot point, because your code won't actually be calling `GC.Collect()`. Nevertheless I didn't down vote the question because there is an objective answer (just longer than I have time to write right now).

Comment: i have lot of memory leak and i find it easy and no harm in calling GC.collect. i know GC.collect affect performance but here i need memory leak to get solved first than performance.

Comment: But as Sam points out, you haven't shown any code that would call your `Dispose()` method, so there's no evidence that the `GC.Collect()` method would even be called in the first place.

Comment: Font objects are very expensive to create.  .NET keeps them cached, assuming that you'll use them again quickly.  You can call the Dispose() method, you should, it doesn't *actually* do what you think it does.  That's okay, you'll never be wrong.  Other than thinking you have a problem, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not, in general, ever need to call `GC.Collect()`. In the code example you included in your question, you should be disposing the `f` object explicitly in the `AssignFont()` method:

```
void AssignFont()
{
    using( Font f = new Font("Arial Narrow", 8))
    {
        // do something with 'f' here
    }
}
```

This takes at face value your code example. If you are passing the reference to the `f` object out of the method somehow, that would change things.

You're not clear what you mean by "leak memory". In general, that's not going to happen in a .NET program. Managed objects are automatically cleaned up by the garbage collector, and correctly-written objects that use unmanaged resources will have finalizers if they have unmanaged resources to clean up, allowing the GC to also clean those up. The most common "leak" is actually "pack-ratting"; i.e. you still hold onto references to objects that you did not intend to, preventing the GC from cleaning them up and no amount of calling `GC.Collect()` will deal with that kind of bug.

Comment: When dealing with objects that deal with GDI (like Font and Bitmap) often you will run out of GDI handles. GDI does not put much pressure to the GC to force a garbage collection so a GC.Collect could help that, but the correct way to solve the problem would be to properly dispose the object.

Comment: This is just a sample code. I know that we should be calling System.Graphics object with Using, my user control code is very large. I am just asking a scenario where if Dispose is not called because developer forgot to call or if any other supernatural reason, is GC.Collect going to release the memory and dispose it correctly.

Comment: `GC.Collect()` will _sometimes_ cause collection to occur sooner than it otherwise would. It's not the right way to fix bugs like this though.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: yes, I suppose an especially active program could wind up exceeding even the currently-generous limits for GDI handles. It's surprising to me that the `Font` class and similar don't use `GC.AddMemoryPressure()` to encourage more aggressive collection, but I suppose since the resource being consumed isn't really memory per se, it makes sense.